# How to configure sudo to ask for user password?

Tags: raspbian, sudo

On Debian, sudo asks for user password by default. On Raspberry Pi OS, it doesn't.

How to configure sudo to ask for user password?

Comment: Edit /etc/sudoers.d/010-pi-nopasswd. The no password setting is in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit `/etc/sudoers.d/010_pi-nopasswd` and remove `NOPASSWD` word from it.

Be careful if you edit it using a regular text editor: if you make a mistake, save the file and quit, you will end up with a broken `sudo` and no way to edit the configuration again (which requires `sudo`).

Either don't close the editor until you have tested the new configuration, or have a `root` session open in another terminal just in case, or use `visudo` to edit the file (`visudo` refuses to save files if there are syntax errors). You can also set a password for `root` which lets you login as `root` and recover your system.

Comment: Thanks! Is it OK to delete this file?

Comment: I ran `sudo rm /etc/sudoers.d/010_*` and so far everything works fine.

Comment: @sunknudsen Yeah, the `pi` user also belongs to the `sudo` group, so it will fall back to the group policy if you remove that file. My only fear is that `apt` may recreate that file again during an upgrade. If you modify it, `apt` will not touch it without asking you.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can just add . to the filename of /etc/sudoers.d/010_pi-nopasswd to disable the NOPASSWD rule. This is stated in the README in the same directory with recent versions of Pi OS. It seems to work for me.

Example:

```
cd /etc/sudoers.d
sudo mv 010_pi-nopasswd .010_pi-nopasswd
```